# Does DidContactBegin Fire Multiple Times at the One Time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

I have a node which makes contact with two other nodes at the same time. What I'm wondering is, when my node make contact with the other two nodes (at the same time), does both the didContactBegin code fire at the same time, or is one didContactBegin processed and then the next.

I would have figured that one fires and then the next, so to make the second or third didContactBegin not fire, I setup a boolean and a timer. But after doing this, I'm starting to think the didContactBegin fires both at the same time, as my code below seems to get double println messages ever so often, but not all the time.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "segment" || contact.bodyB.node?.name == "segment" {

        if boolean == true {
            boolean = false
            timerResetBoolNextAction.invalidate()
            timerResetBoolNextAction = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("ResetBoolean"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

            println("boolean is true")
        }

   }  

}


func ResetBoolean() {

    boolNextAction = true

}
```

Anyway, the main thing I want to know is does the didContactBegin fire all at once or does it queue. Because if it does queue, I believe there must be something else wrong with my code.

Comment: What do you mean "ever so often?" What changes when it does/does not call the function twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will only go in to the if statement if one "or" the other is true so if they both happen at the same time the if statement will read the first clause and it will be true and will go straight in and execute your code "once only". the statement would need to be true again on the next frame or loop for it to happen again.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes this does answer my question. I was hoping that each statement would read after one another, because I didn't know a way around it otherwise. After receive your post, I went over and over and over my code (not the above code, that was just an example), and it turns out the timer I had implemented was incorrect and have now amended it. Thanks for the clarification, I know where to look now.